# RESTful URL doesn't appear to be mapping right to url Using Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am having trouble getting my url-mapping correct.

My Controller looks like this...

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/report")
public class ReportController extends CatalogManagementBaseController { 
...
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET) 
public @ResponseBody String test(Model model) throws Exception{
    return "Worked!";
}
}
```

And my url-mapping looks like this..`

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>`
```

If I change the url mapping to / it works but I want the dispatcher to only handle the requests sent to ../rest/...

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Could it be something to do with the inheritance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the dispatcher to be mapped to `/rest/*` then I believe you should remove this prefix from the controller's `@RequestMapping`, i.e. only have `RequestMapping(/report)`.

The mapping you have configured would result in the Controller listening to requests on `/rest/rest/report`

Answer (score 3):

If your servlet is mapped to `/rest/*` then the controller should be annotated with:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/report")
```

Comment: I will have to try this, I solved it by using just / and it hasn't effected the static content yet but I will try this.